# Minimize number of API calls

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I have three distinct API calls A,M,T
I have some set of rules for which I have to call these APIs in sequence, sometimes output of one API call is used as input for the other.

eg:

Rule 1 = M -> A -> A -> M -> T

Rule 2 = A -> M -> A -> A -> M -> A -> T

Multiple inputs can be combined and be input to an API call to get multiple outputs. Partial output from any API call can be used as Input to another API.

so number of distinct API calls for the above 2 rules can be compressed as

A -> M -> A -> A -> M -> A -> T

It is reduced to totally 7 API calls

What I am looking for is how to generalise this compression if there were n number of rules and each rule can any sequence of API calls.
Please quide me in correct direction like any algorithm, computer science/Mathematical field that generalizes this problem.

Comment: You listed the same sequence for rule 2 two times, so there is no "compression"

Comment: no they are different, just that they are overlapping.

Comment: ah, I misunderstood you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive generator function to get all overlapping combinations, and the find the optimal result via `max`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest as zl, product
def combine(rules):
   for i in product(*[enumerate(k) for k in rules]):
      rest = [r[ind+1:] for r, (ind, _) in zip(rules, i)]
      start = [[*filter(None, j)] for j in zl(*[r[:ind] for r, (ind, _) in zip(rules, i)])]
      if not any(rest):
         yield start+[[b for _, b in i]]
      else:
          for b in combine(list(filter(None, rest))):
             yield start + [[j for _, j in i]] + b

r1 = 'M -> A -> A -> M -> T'
r2 = 'A -> M -> A -> A -> M -> A -> T'
k = set([tuple(map(tuple, i)) for i in combine([r1.split(' -> '), r2.split(' -> ')])])
print(max(k, key=lambda x:sum(len(set(i)) != len(i) for i in x)))
```

Output:

```
(('A',), ('M', 'M'), ('A', 'A'), ('A', 'A'), ('M', 'M'), ('A',), ('T', 'T'))
```

The resulting output is the matched pairings of the two rules:

```
A - <no match> => ('A',)
M - M => ('M', 'M')
A - A => ('A', 'A')
A - A => ('A', 'A')
M - M => ('M', 'M')
A - <no match> => ('A',)
T - T => ('T', 'T')
```

Comment: Thanks Ajax! I am trying to understand your code.